# XCTest in Xcode 7: how to verify some text exists in the view

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest

I am running Xcode 7 on El Capitan (10.11). I am using the new record and playback feature for XCUITest.  I am using Swift not Objective-C.  Here is the code I have generated thus far:

```
    func testButton2() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.tabBars.buttons["Location"].tap() //tab bar tap
    app.buttons["Button"].tap()  // button tap
    //now verify some text appears in this tab view

}
```

I want to verify some text appears in the same view within a UILabel after button is tapped.

Any ideas?

I know there is a bunch of asserts listed here:

```
http://iosunittesting.com/xctest-assertions/
```

Comment: Verify tome text where? In a UILabel? Someother View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have reference to your label properly set up:

```
func testButton2() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.tabBars.buttons["Location"].tap() //tab bar tap
    app.buttons["Button"].tap()  // button tap
    //now verify some text appears in this tab view
    XCTAssertEqual(myLabel.text, "some text", "should be equal")

}
```

Comment: can I a stupid question?  How can I access a ViewController's UILabel from the XCTestCase class?

Comment: @lilredindy I can't give full explanation because of time right now, so I will leave with the WWDC video covering UI testing. I will try to get back to this this evening. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/

Answer (score 1):

```
func testButton2() {

   let app = XCUIApplication()
   app.tabBars.buttons["Location"].tap() //tab bar tap
   app.buttons["Button"].tap()  // button tap
   //now verify some text appears in this tab view
   XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts.elementBoundByIndex(0).label, "some text", "should be equal") }
```

Comment: `app.staticTexts.matchingIdentifier(<#T##identifier: String##String#>)`